Would This Be a Good Bipolar AND Gate?
In my last question, I asked about this schematic that I made:

My question was answered and I got some good advice, so I recreated the circuit with the new knowledge in mind, which looks like this:

My question is, does this new circuit make more sense compared to what I had made in my last one? What are the faults of the circuit above?
This may not be a good question to put onto the forums, but I am just trying to understand this circuitry better and see no other way of doing it in a simple manner.
Here are the two data sheets I am using:
L128-RED1003500000
2N2222
If you think I should add more information to make this a better question, just let me know.
Thank you for any help in advance.

Seems OK to me. A 1k or 1k5 in bases should switch on 120mA load for sure. How do you control the base signals (manual switches, some external signals,…)?

For right now, a manual switch; a four-pinned button.

You have the design captured for simulation. Does your simulation say that it meets all the requirements you have for it (input and output voltages, speed, load current capability, ...) or not?

@SimonFitch It's true that when Q2 is off and Q1 input is high, that Q1's emitter will go high. But if Q2 is off to start, Q1 input then goes high, and then Q2's input goes high (turning Q2 on, now) then Q1's emitter is pulled back down by Q2's collector. So if both inputs are high, the LED does turn on.

What is your definition for 'good'? If this circuit works properly under the conditions you need it to work, then it works, otherwise if it does not work under those conditions, you need to change the circuit or the conditions so that it works.

The problem I have with the circuit is that it cannot be generally applied as an AND gate. You can make one of them work fine. But it becomes a more serious problem when combining them.
For example, your \$R_2\$ input doesn't look like your \$R_3\$ input. They aren't the same and cannot be used without knowing this fact.
Let's look at a simplified table where I apply either \$0\:\text{V}\$ or \$5\:\text{V}\$ to the inputs in a way that all four combinations can be considered:
$$\begin{matrix}
R_2 & R_3 & I_{R_2} & I_{R_3}
\\\\
0\:\text{V}& 0\:\text{V} & 0\:\text{mA}& 0\:\text{mA}
\\
0\:\text{V}& 5\:\text{V} & 0\:\text{mA}& \approx 2.9\:\text{mA}
\\
5\:\text{V}& 0\:\text{V} & 0\:\text{mA}& 0\:\text{mA}
\\
5\:\text{V}& 5\:\text{V} & \approx 2.9\:\text{mA}& \approx 2.9\:\text{mA}
\end{matrix}$$
Skim over the table and see if you notice a difference. Do you see that the lower (\$R_3\$ on your schematic) resistor always sinks \$\approx 2.9\:\text{mA}\$ load when that input is set to \$5\:\text{V}\$? But that the upper resistor behaves differently -- in that it may, or may not, need to handle \$\approx 2.9\:\text{mA}\$ depending upon what the other, lower input state is?
Having an input loading that varies, itself, depending upon what the other inputs happen to be isn't a scalable idea.
Here's the results from a simplified run using LTspice:

There you can see that the bright red diode current (using a faked \$R_1\$ in this case so showing here \$I_{R_1}\$) is only active when both inputs are at \$5\:\text{V}\$.
So it does appear to act like an AND gate. And it does work as a teaching example. I grant it that much.
But it isn't good. Not in my book.
There are other considerations, as well. The inputs don't behave the same in other (and potentially important) ways, too. But it's enough to drill down on the above to make the point.

Could you elaborate as to why bipolar logic gates aren’t good? I’m not able with to find much online.

@SqidyP You misunderstand. Bipolar logic gates are quite good. The wild success of TTL is manifest. Your topology using them is the problem. Designed well, bipolar carried decades of logic used in industry.

Ah, I see. Thank you very much.
